# why Spring boot 2.4.3 has migration issues related entityManagerFactory bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I had a working application using spring boot 1.5.9
After i upgrade spring boot to latest 2.4.3, facing issues with

`an interface with @Reposiroty - required a bean of type testRepository`
then added @EnableJPAConfiguration to bootRunner got below error

`required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found`

If i a write LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean with dataSource configuration, i could see the application starts.

I dont really see these details from this Migration Guide
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Kindly Please help me understanding this puzzle. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't annotate interfaces with `@Repository` when using Spring Data JPA that is actually not what is detecting the beans. So remove the `@Repository`.

Comment: Can you please share some more code

Comment: If you are writing your own EMFactoryBean, you have to name the bean as "entityManagerFactory". `@Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")`

Comment: @deinum, as mentioned it was working for 1.5.x, you mean as part of 2.4.x we dont use ```@Repository``` for an interface..?